# Waiting values from child window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

`<Asp:Button ID=... onclick="openChildWindow()"`

```
<asp:label ID="label1"  ....>
```

I have a web page containing a button and a label. When I click the button, openCHildWindow() execute:

```
openChildWindow()
{ //open child window...
//some other functions....
}
```

in the child windows, there is a textbox where I can enter some thing.
And my problem is: IF i need the child window to transmit the value in textbox to parent window, is it possible for 
`//some other functions` 
wait until parent window gets the value from child window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can have the parent window "wait" for the child window, or if you would want to because you will most likely get a "long running script" message, but I know that you can access the parent window from the child using

`window.opener`

so you should be able to do something like this before you close the child window:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value = myTextboxValue;
window.close();
```

of maybe even better just call a function in the parent window:

```
window.opener.ParentWindowFunction(myTextboxValue);
window.close();
```

Try looking through this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice